# show that key recovery is not possible in a computationally secure system

Tags: security-definition, computational-complexity-theory

(G, E, D) is a computationally secure encryption scheme over the message space $\{0,1\}^n$. Show that the probability that a PPT adversary can recover the key after seeing the encryption of a random (uniform distribution) message is negligible.

---

I want to show that if the attacker A has the ability to recover the key with non-negligible probability, e.g. 20%, it breaks semantic security, as A can guess much better $f(M)$ than a blind attacker A' that does not see the cipher.

BUT I'm stumped, as suppose $f(M)$ distribution is very skewed and the most frequent value occurs 30% of the time, the blind attacker A' can simply always guess that and beat A, thus not breaking semantic security...

---

Reminder - semantic security definition I'm using: $Pr_K[A(E_K(M))=f(M)]\leq Pr_K[A'(1^n)=f(M)]+neg(n)$

Comment: Then, it is already not semantical security. You should assume that the blind has negligible advantage.

Comment: what do you mean @kelalaka ? the blind attacker currently has an advantage - it can guess with 30% and no attacker can guess better.

Comment: If the blind attacker has the non-negligible advantage then how the scheme can have semantical security?

Comment: @kelalaka - semantic security means that no attacker A that can see the cipher can guess better than the blind attacker A' that does not see the cipher. It does not have a non-negligible advantage, as the attacker A can also guess the most frequent value and they both will have 30% accuracy...

Comment: Try allowing $A$ a sensible guess in the event that they fail to recover the key.

Comment: @DanielShiu - but how will i know that happened? if they simply get the wrong key and don't know that?

Comment: Then their incorrect key will provide a decryption to a random element of the message space.

Comment: @DanielShiu - it will? will it simply sample from the message distribution? how do I know it won't be biased towards a very rare message m with very rare f(m)?

Comment: In that case you could develop a distinguisher on the scheme.